# My content disappear after adding react Query to project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

**So i im working with typescript and react and i wanted to get data from api.. so i added react query to the project.**

```
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./components/Navbar";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Body } from "./components/Body";

function App() {
  //
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  //
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav />
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Body />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**And**

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

//
export const Body = () => {
  //

  const { data: meme = {}, status } = useQuery(["id"], () => {
    axios.get("").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  });

  const defaultImage =
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0a/bb/e5/0abbe546e479edc1eb62f5a8ccd66328.jpg";

  return (
    <div className="body__container">
      <main>
        <div className="input__container">
          <input placeholder="First text" />
          <input placeholder="second text" />
        </div>

        {/*  */}
        <button> Get new image </button>

        {/*  */}
        <img src={defaultImage} height="400px" width="400px" />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But after all this the content of the webpage disappear and only showing white page.

i checked console and im getting this error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkcl3.jpg)
**
im not using useEffect anywhere so im confused.**

ive tried using @tanstack/react-query and restarting the server same blank page and error

Comment: Dude the return in query function, its misssing,
useQuery(["id"], () => {
    return axios.get("").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
  });

Comment: Did console.log return anything? Where are you showing what "meme" is on the render portion? Assuming {meme} is text. I'd expect to see it `{meme}` maybe above the button.

Comment: i have not actually called any api and if i comment out the "useQuery" the problem still persist... so i dont think the issue is from Body.

Comment: Please create a minimum reproducible example. Otherwise we have no idea what the error is.

Comment: Try moving the QueryClientProvider higher up the tree in App:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return from queryFn.

Try this:

```
  const { data: meme = {}, status } = useQuery(["id"], () => axios.get("/").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Comment: Your version doesn't return either...